# Xubutu, right click so slow

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, xfce

I'm on Xubuntu 13.10 64 bit. I'm running Xfce4 version 4.10, Thunar version 1.6.3

If you right click on the desktop, the menu might never show up, if you right click in Thunar, you'll have to wait like 10s or more for it to show up.

If you right click in Thunar -> create a new document, you'll have to wait like 30s for the menu to show up. (sometimes it never does).

*There's only one similar question, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96216/right-click-on-xubuntu-home-screen-is-slow-is-it-normal), I followed the instructions in the accepted answer, it doesn't fix it,  the right click menu is as slow as ever. The second answer, well it's not my first time. I need a third answer that wasn't given there.*

Comment: @DKBose only xubuntu, I didnt install other window managers or file managers, and its on my pc, not a virtual machine

Comment: @DKBose right now i don't have another machine :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9914) in Xfce `4.10`. It has (probably) been fixed in the upcoming `4.12`, namely in the `xfdesktop 4.11.2` development release.

You can test the fix by adding the [Xfce 4.12 packages PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.12) and updating your packages (do note that this is *unreleased*, development software). In any case, this release seems to solve the issue on my system.

Comment: That worked like a charm, there's still a minor issue with the `create new document dialog` I'll ask a different question about it, but 95% problem solved.

Comment: `xfce4-about` still showing 4.10, is that normal? I updated it this way http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-xfce-4-12-on-ubuntu-13-10-ubuntu-13-04-ubuntu-12-10-and-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: Probably. I get `4.10` here, too, even though I'm running all latest development packages. Nothing to worry about.