# Xfce4 create new document, remove history

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, xfce

I'm on Xubuntu 14.04. 64 bit. [I'm not sure about the xfce version I'm using](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447637/xfce-top-panel-indicator-problem). I had kinda [the same problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424406/xubutu-right-click-so-slow) on 13.10, it hunts me on 14.04 and upgrading doesn't seem to work.

When I click right click, if go over (even by mistake) to create new document, the computer freezes for a while

[image]

I think I know why, it tries to search for previously edited files

[image]

How to disable that feature forever? By the way I uninstalled the default editor, abiword I think. I disabled everything here, didn't solve it

[image]

I just want to disable the right click menu from searching to previously edited files. I don't want that feature.

Comment: You should empty your `$HOME/Templates` directory and try again.

Comment: @Xubu-Tur it works, what the templates folder is for?

Comment: [What is the “Templates” folder in the home directory for?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94734/what-is-the-templates-folder-in-the-home-directory-for)

Comment: @Xubu-Tur thank you, I flagged my question as possible dupe, didn't know that before, I'll leave it, in case someone has the same problem as me